# How can I gain more weight and a 6 pack?

Tags: gym, weight-gain, muscle-gain

I'm 16, 6'1 and I weigh 132 pounds. I have checked and this is under what I should weigh.

I currently go to a gym every other day. I'm looking to gain a bit more weight, muscle and hopefully a 6 pack. I am tall but skinny.

I cannot do some exercise due to I have hypermobility. But I can do most as long as I remember not to lock my arms or legs out. Due to this, I cannot do some arm workouts, is there other exercise that will build muscle?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a very similar situation to you at your age. One thing you have to understand is your metabolism is likely at or close to it's peak right now.

Gaining weight is as simple as more calories in then calories out. I would suggest counting your calories for a few days and seeing how many you're currently eating per day. Then try adding 250 per day(preferably healthy calories, but at your age/size it doesn't really matter). Once you are doing that comfortably, try adding another 250 per day.

As for working out, try focusing on compound movements and low rep ranges. For example, deadlifts, squats, and bench press are very good compound movements. Try to hit around 4-8 reps.

Even this you can't expect to gain a lot of weight quick. About 0.5 lbs per week is sustainable.

Let me know if you have any other questions!